# How to create a where query function in the Crud Repo in Hibernate?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am currently learning spring boot and hibernate

I created a Staff Entity and Staff repo

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "staffs")
public class Staff {

    private String name;
    private String gender;
    private String email;

    private Integer mobile;

    private String joined;

    @Id
    private String staffID;

    private String password;

    private Integer isAdminStaff;

    private Integer instID;

getters and setter....

}


public interface StaffRepository extends CrudRepository <Staff,String> {
}
```

Now I need to create a method in StaffRepository for user login

The query is

```
SELECT * FROM staffs WHERE email = 'john@example.com' AND password = 'aabc123xy' AND instID = 13
```

I need to create a method like this in staff repo

```
@AutoWired
StaffRepository staffRepo

Staff staff= staffRepo.login("john@example.com","aabc123xy",13);// execute above where query

if (staff != null) youLoggedIn();
else wrongCredits();
```

How to implement this ?

Also help for this query ::

```
SELECT enrolled_courses.enrollID,student.name,student.studentid from enrolled_courses INNER JOIN student where enrolled_courses.studentid = student.studentid AND student.instID = 13 AND enrolled_courses.courseid = '13I01C'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JPA method naming query this way

```
Staff findByEmailAndPasswordAndInstId(String email, String password, Integer id);
```

Use this in your `StaffRepository` and call this using your data

```
Staff staff= staffRepo.findByEmailAndPasswordAndInstId("john@example.com","aabc123xy",13);
```

Note: Assuming by this criterion their will be unique staff

Comment: one help please ... is there any inbuilt method for this query :: SELECT enrolled_courses.enrollID,student.name,student.studentid from enrolled_courses INNER JOIN student where enrolled_courses.studentid = student.studentid AND student.instID = 13 AND enrolled_courses.courseid = '13I01C'

Comment: @LordCommander It's a completely different query. Please post another question with used entity and their relations so that it will more clear your intent.